# Using Orchard CMS with existing ASP.Net Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-membership, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

My company is thinking to use Orchard CMS as the framework to our intranet application. Speaking theoretically, it should work; however, I'm facing troubles finding information about using it with existing setup. We already have about database, from the old application, we already have our accounts, logins, etc. based on ASP.Net Memebership Provider, and we already have our own custom authorisation, roles, etc.

Can someone guides me to the direction where I find information about how to "plug" Orchard CMS to an existing ASP.Net Memebership Provider, and apply custom authorisation logic?

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you need to override Orchard's `IMembershipProvider`.
Have a look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173152/588894)**  and also at Piotr's blog post **[blog post](http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/most-useful-orchard-extension-points#.VT9cfSGqpBc)**